# SharePoint Foundation 2013: Is it possible to dynamically filter document libraries?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, filter

I'm developing a website and, as part of the specifications, I need to have a number of documents in a central document library, then only display a subset of them to the user at any one time depending on which are relevant.  Let's say that I need to filter out the ones for which the value in the GUID column matches a certain value.  I know that it is possible to make a static filter, but I would like to be able to filter it dynamically (ideally using JavaScript) so that the documents relevant to each user can be pulled out when needed.  I am using SharePoint Foundation 2013 and am also restricted from using non-OOTB web parts/apps.  Is this possible without a lengthy workaround?

Other sources have suggested using a data view web part or a filter web part, both of which appear to be unavailable in the Foundation version.  It has also been suggested that I should be able to filter a column using the default UI, and using a placeholder value that takes the value of a token from the URL, but it is also unclear as to how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter list dynamically using Query Strings. The same strategy you can apply for creating dynamic experiences as you want

Sample syntax is

```
https://siteurl/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=LinkTitle&FilterValue1=somevalue
```

Change `LinkTitle` to the metadata column name
Change `somevalue` to the value you want to filter up on

Comment: Does this look like valid syntax?

`AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=GUID&FilterValue1=67f9e1f8-69d0-44ed-9292-ab2b3898a324`

I tried this but it's filtering out everything when I wasn't expecting it to.

Comment: You can create the URL - First open AllItems view and then filter using the out of the box way. Then copy the URL from browser address bar and use it

Comment: Unfortunately the URL doesn't change when I set filters that way, it just remains the same and the filtering appears to happen behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could put users in to Sharepoint user Groups, then find a way to filter on the documents depending on which user group a user is in. You'd need to label all of your documents according to which Groups should see which documents.

You could tag/label your documents using meta-data (if that is available with the Foundation version of SP?).  This blog http://sharepointmaven.com/tag/metadata/ has lots of useful info on Meta-Data.

OR, maybe it is not something that your requirements would permit, do something simple like adding a 'Category' field - then labelling the documents according to which category they fit in to.  Then configure views based on this.

e.g.

CATEGORY - Engineering, Human Resources, Quality, Manufacturing, Health & Safety.  The views you set up would then filter based on the value (e.g. Engineering).

Comment: Foundation does support metadata, and it does support the filtering of documents by metadata, by typing in a fixed value to the UI (and this is what I'm doing currently).  I can't find a way to change that filter value dynamically, however.  So extending your example, I can't find a way to make it display Engineering documents at one point in time, but then change it to display Quality instead later.